# Export mysql Error 1064 <42000>: You have an error in your sql syntax

Tags: export, mysql

I have seen many replies to this question, but none of the solutions worked for me, so i am repeating the same question.
I am using mysql 5.5.30 on windows xp.
I am able to open mysql command line by giving this command:
    `d:\mysql\usr\local\mysql\bin>mysql –uroot –proot`

But when i use the same username and password to export a database by giving this command:
     `mysql>mysqldump -uroot -proot svga3 > dbsqlfile.sql`
I GET THIS ERR:

```
Error 1064 <42000>: You have an error in your sql syntax: check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'mysqldump -uroot -proot svga3 > dbsqlfile.sql
```

AFTER seeing many on responses and tried all combinations of the same line, it does't work, need help!

Other option tried:

```
 mysqldump -u root -p root svga3 > dbsqlfile.sql
 mysqldump -uroot -p svga3 > dbsqlfile.sql
 mysqldump -u root -p=root svga3 > dbsqlfile.sql
 mysqldump -u -p svga3 > dbsqlfile.sql
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't run `mysqldump` from a `mysql` shell, it needs to run from the prompt.

`d:\mysql\usr\local\mysql\bin>mysqldump ...`

Comment: Kyra is right. You can run system commands from within the mysql command-line client using the *system* command (only on Unix systems) as stated here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-commands.html .